# I wiped my /etc/yum.repos.d

Tags: centos, configuration, yum

I think I seriously messed things up on my EC2 instance which I'm currently hacking on. I tried to install some rpmfusion repository from which to install FFMPEG, but it broke things and I wasn't able to do any updates or install anything.

So, I ran a pretty straightforward rm command: `rm /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-*`. I think this really messed things up, though, as I can't seem to find `rpmbuild` which I need to install FFMPEG.

Can anyone help me recover from this? I don't have access to the EC2 control panel, otherwise I'd just up another instance and start over. Can anyone instruct me on how to simply install FFMPEG on a CentOS-like OS?

Comment: I am just curious why do you want to install ffmpeg on a server hosted in cloud?

Comment: Probably going to use ffmpeg as a base to stream video - like using it with ffserver.

Comment: Advice to avoid this particular problem in the future: keep `/etc` under version control. `etckeeper` makes this totally painless, see [this article](http://scentos.blogspot.com/2010/11/install-etckeeper.html) or more generally [etckeeper+centos](http://www.google.com/search?q=etckeeper+centos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the REPO RPMS here:

```
http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration
```

You probably want to find the version that matches what you have installed and do:

```
yum reinstall packagename
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a repo file for base package

1. `vim /etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Base.repo`
2. You have to change Centos-Base.repo like this:

   ```
   [base]
   name=CentOS-$releasever – Base
   #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
   baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
   ```
3. save file
   :wq
4. Now try installing/re-installing any software

   ```
   yum reinstall ekiga
   ```

   Output

   ```
   Installed:
   ekiga.x86_64 0:4.0.1-4.el7
   ```

if this installs you are all set.

Comment: However adding third party repositories can also be done: [http://tecadmin.net/top-5-yum-repositories-for-centos-rhel-systems/]